# Creating a single static library from several dependent projects

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I am attempting to create a static library wrapping the SQL Cipher functionality along with all of the associated dependencies i.e. OpenSSL, SQLite and some other wrapper e.g. FMDB.

The problem is the complete lack of documentation from Apple. The example they provide at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/iOSStaticLibraries.pdf is miserly and useless in all but the most simple of circumstances.

The issue I have revolves around the concept of creating a static library that links to multiple other dependent Xcode projects. I have the following structure in Xcode within a Static Library project:

[image]

I have created all of the necessary links etc and utilise LIPO to create a universal binary. The problem is that the output generates a library class for each of the projects so I end up with the following:

[image]

I may be entirely missing the point but I was expecting a single entry point library and not the individual libraries.

I have read that Xcode project resources will not be included in the Static Library build and will still have to be handled by the consuming application/project i.e. by adding them individually! Does this rule apply in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation it would appear this is the desired outcome.

To resolve, I utilised the libtool command to combine the libraries.